# Replacing values from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fix discrepancies in a column from one df to a column in another.
The tables are not sorted as well.
How can i do this using python. Example:

df1

```
Age        Name

40        Sid Jones
50        Alex, Bot
32        Tony Jar
65        Fred, Smith
24        Brad, Mans
```

df2

```
Age        Name

24        Brad Mans
32        Tony Jar
40        Sid Jones
65        Fred Smith
50        Alex Bot
```

I need to replace the values in df2 to match those in df1 as you can see in my example the discrepancies are commas in the names.

Expected outcome for df2:

```
Age        Name

24        Brad, Mans
32        Tony Jar
40        Sid Jones
65        Fred, Smith
50        Alex, Bot
```

The values in df2 should be changed to match the df1s values.

Comment: is df1  not  the output ?

Comment: How is df1 and your expected output different ? From this example it is not coming out!! Also if you just want to sort..read about sort function

Comment: I'm trying to change df2 to add the names with commas that are missing from df2 but are in df1 into the df2 name column

Answer (score 2):

Create a column in `df1` with commas removed from the `Name` column

```
df1['Name_nocomma'] = df1.Name.str.replace(',', '')
```

merge `df1` to `df2` using `Name_nocomma` & `Name` to get the *corrected* `Name` create a new version of `df2`

```
df2_out = df2.merge(df1, left_on='Name', right_on='Name_nocomma', how='left')[['Age_x', 'Name_x', 'Name_y']]
```

use combine_first to coalesce `Name_y` & `Name_x` into a new column `Name`

```
df2_out['Name'] = df2_out.Name_y.combine_first(df2_out.Name_x)
```

drop / rename the intermediate columns

```
del df1['Name_nocomma']
del df2_out['Name_x']
del df2_out['Namy_y']
df2_out.rename({'Age_x': 'Age'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df2_out
#outputs:
   Age         Name
0   24    Brad Mans
1   32     Tony Jar
2   40    Sid Jones
3   65   Fred Smith
4   50     Alex Bot
```

Answer (score 0):

you need [sort](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

```
df1.sort(by=['Age'], inplace = True)
df2.sort(by=['Age'], inplace = True)

result_df = df1.append(df2)
```